# MySQLdb.cursor.execute can't run multiple queries

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

We're trying to run SQL files containing multiple insert statements as a single query, but it seems `rollback` fails when any of the statements contain an error.

MySQLd configuration:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES
default-storage-engine = innodb
```

Python code:

```
from contextlib import closing
import MySQLdb
database_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root")
with closing(database_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    database_connection.begin()
    cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name')
    cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE db_name')
    cursor.execute('USE db_name')
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE table_name(first_field INTEGER)')
with closing(database_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    try:
        database_connection.begin()
        cursor.execute('USE db_name')
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1)')
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("non-integer value")')
        database_connection.commit()
    except Exception as error:
        print("Exception thrown: {0}".format(error))
        database_connection.rollback()
        print("Rolled back")
with closing(database_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    try:
        database_connection.begin()
        cursor.execute('USE db_name')
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1); INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("non-integer value")')
        database_connection.commit()
    except:
        print("Exception thrown: {0}".format(error))
        database_connection.rollback()
        print("Rolled back")
```

Expected result: "Exception thrown" and "Rolled back" printed twice.

Actual result with MySQL-python 1.2.4:

```
Exception thrown: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'non-integer value' for column 'first_field' at row 1")
Rolled back
Exception thrown: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'non-integer value' for column 'first_field' at row 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    print("Rolled back")
  File ".../python-2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 154, in __exit__
    self.thing.close()
  File ".../virtualenv-python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 100, in close
    while self.nextset(): pass
  File ".../virtualenv-python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 132, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'non-integer value' for column 'first_field' at row 1")
```

What gives? Do we really have to parse the SQL to split up statements (with all the escape and quote handling that entails) to run them in multiple `execute`s?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like all [Python DB-API 2.0 implementations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the `cursor.execute()` method is designed take only **one** statement, because it makes guarantees about the state of the cursor afterward.

Use the [`cursor.executemany()` method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) instead. Do note that, [as per the DB-API 2.0 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany):

> Use of this method for an operation which produces one or more result sets constitutes undefined behavior, and the implementation is permitted (but not required) to raise an exception when it detects that a result set has been created by an invocation of the operation.

Using this for multiple `INSERT` statements should be just fine:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (%s)',
    [(1,), ("non-integer value",)]
)
```

If you need to execute a series of disparate statements like from a script, then for most cases you can just split the statements on `;` and feed each statement to `cursor.execute()` separately.

Comment: I'm not seeing where `.execute` DB-API specification prohibits multiple statements. The mere existence of the `nextset` method implies that `execute` is the right function for multiple queries. `executemany` is definitely not: not only does the standard warn against it, the function's signature and purpose is a completely different operation from `execute`.
What guarantees on cursor state are maintained by only allowing a single statement?

Comment: @Thanatos: you appear to be confusing results with the operation that produces them. `execute()` takes **one** query or command (the wording is clearly singular in the specs). The warning on `executemany()` concerns queries that produce result sets; specifically `SELECT`. The OP is using `INSERT`, which does not produce a result set so the warning *doesn't apply*. They are using the exact same query in each case, only the values are variable, which is exactly what executemany is great for: repeating the same query with different parameter values.

Comment: @Thanatos: if you wanted to execute a script, then there is no provision for that in the DB-API. Some adapters do implement some form of script execution (like `sqlite3`'s [`executescript()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executescript), but that's not part of the API spec.

Comment: Personally, I feel like you're over-reading the PEP at that point. Why even should the PEP (and implementors of the PEP) only allow a single query? It makes it *significantly* more onerous to have a .sql file that Python executes: you're either forced to implement and entire SQL parser, or have to wrap the SQL in a microlanguage that separates out the commands, completely breaking the ability to feed it to the proper DB client. In short, the PEP actively fights the programmer's needs at that point; it's infuriating.

Comment: @Thanatos: `execute()` is a cursor method. A cursor models **one** resultset, not multiple. You can't access the results of multiple queries, execute thus only allows you to execute one statement at a time.

Comment: *a cursor models **one** resultset*; if that were true, there would be no point to the `nextset` method, which gets the next result set. Trying to state that "well, that's only used for `executemany`" only proves my point that the PEP actively fights the user (the cursor only supports multiple result sets, but only in the case of running the same query multiple times? why? that is an utterly arbitrary restriction with consequences for common use cases) and is bad specification.

Comment: @Thanatos: I oversimplified, but only slightly. A cursor models one query or command (the documentation is quite clear on that, feel free to canvas the dbapi committee to replace `a query or command` with `one query or command`). `cursor.nextset()` is needed when you use the cursor to execute a *stored procedure* that produces multiple resultsets. At least Sybase, MySQL and Oracle support this, IIRC (although Oracle uses a [different method to retrieve those sets](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.getimplicitresults)).

Comment: I feel you have just misunderstood the utility of a cursor in a database query. In most other languages, database cursors work exactly the same. If you want to discuss this further, this comment thread is not the place; you are free to open a discusson on the [Python DB special interest group list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/db-sig).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to pass `multi=True` to `execute` when using multiple statements, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

**Update:** This applies to the `mysql.connector` module, not `MySQLdb` used in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is no way to do this in [`MySQLdb`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) (aka. `MySQL-python`), so we ended up just `communicate`ing the data to `subprocess.Popen([mysql, ...], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` and checking the `returncode`.

Answer (score 3):

Tried the `multi=True` method, but ended up splitting the file by semi and looping through. Obviously not going to work if you have escaped semis, but seemed like the best method for me.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for statement in script.split(';'):
        if len(statement) > 0:
             cursor.execute(statement + ';')
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
for _ in cursor.execute(query, multi=True): 
    pass
```

This works for me!

And according to the doc, this is the right thing to do, cursor.execute() returns an iterator and only when the contents in the iterator is consumed, will the commit be successful.

Comment: This causes a StopIteration exception for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `mysql` program via Popen will definitely work, but if you want to just use an existing connection (and cursor), the `sqlparse` package has a `split` function that will split into statements. I'm not sure what the compatiblity is like, but I have a script that does:

```
with open('file.sql', 'rb') as f:
    for statement in sqlparse.split(f.read()):
        if not statement:
            continue
        cur.execute(statement)
```

It's only ever fed DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements, but works for me.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse

Answer (score -3):

**use below line item to execute statement :**

```
for _ in cursor.execute(query, multi=True): pass
```