# multiple queries from mysql command line

Tags: python, mysql

I have multiple mysql queries that I wanted to run from command line

Is there anyway to run them all without writing it to a file?
Basically I have a very large string which have all the queries separated by ";"
But it does contain new line charachter etc so its not letting me execute that string.So how do I serialize that string in python to a valid argument for below command

mysql --defaults-file=/sql.cnf {DBNAME} < serialized_string

Comment: Why not just remove newlines? E.G., echo "my string" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g' | mysql --defaults-file=/sql.cnf

Comment: Its not just about new lines i have multiple create table statements and other stuff also it starts throwing diff errors like """-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' """

Comment: Did you try opening mysql as a filehandle and printing to it? Can you not use MySQLdb instead?

Comment: I have around 600 queries.I dont want to write cursor.execute() for each of them

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518677/mysqldb-cursor-execute-cant-run-multiple-queries