# How to truncate and insert on the same transaction using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a `production_table` and `stage_table`.
I have a python script that runs for few hours and generate data in the `stage_table`.
I want at the end of the script to `COPY` data from the `stage_table` to the `production_table`.

Basically this is what I want:

```
1. TRUNCATE production_table
2. COPY production_table from stage_table
```

This is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text as sa_text
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://  AMAZON AWS")
engine.execute(sa_text('''TRUNCATE TABLE {1}; COPY TABLE {1} from {0}'''.format(stage_table, production_table)).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

This should generate :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE production_table; COPY TABLE production_table from stage_table
```

However this doesn't work.

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064,
>   u"You have an error in your SQL syntax;

How can I make it work? and how can I make sure that the TRUNCATE and COPY are together. I don't want TRUNCATE to happen if COPY aborts.

Comment: Does MySQL have a COPY statement?

Comment: @IljaEverilä This could be part of the problem.. ? There are 2 M records to import per day... Insert operation may be very slow.. this is why COPY was created. isn't it?

Comment: @IljaEverilä  Change it to  `TRUNCATE TABLE {1}; INSERT INTO {1} SELECT * FROM {0}`   also doesn't work. same error.

Comment: There is no `COPY` statement in `MySQL`, so inserting is probably your only choice. Another _slightly_ wonky solution might be altering the table names (essentially making your staging table your production table, and production table your staging table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to handle multiple statements in a single transaction in SQLAlchemy would be to begin an explicit transaction and execute each statement in it:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(statement_1)
    conn.execute(statement_2)
    ...
```

As to your original attempt, there is no COPY statement in MySQL. Some other DBMS do have something of the kind. Also not all DB-API drivers support multiple statements in a [single query or command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518677/mysqldb-cursor-execute-cant-run-multiple-queries), at least out of the box, which would seem to be the case here as well. See [this issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/637) and the [related note in the PyMySQL ChangeLog](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/c51b47e3c6fa0d8b8090a6b25f7168ed68082dea/CHANGELOG#L12-L15).

The biggest issue is that [not all statements in MySQL can be rolled back](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html), of which the most common are DDL statements. In other words you simply cannot execute `TRUNCATE [TABLE] ...` in the same transaction as the following `INSERT INTO ...` and must design your application around that limitation. As suggested in the comments by Christian W. you could perhaps create an entirely new table from your staging table and rename, or just swap the production and staging tables. `RENAME TABLE ...` cannot be rolled back either, but at least you'd reduce the window for error, and could undo the changes since the original production table would still be there, just under a new name. You could then remove the original production table when all else is done. Here's something that demonstrates the idea, but requires manual intervention, if something goes awry:

```
# No point in faking transactions here, since MySQL in use.
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE new_production AS SELECT * FROM stage_table")
engine.execute("RENAME TABLE production_table TO old_production")
engine.execute("RENAME TABLE new_production TO production_table")
# Point of no return:
engine.execute("DROP TABLE old_production")
```

Comment: Where the .execution_options(autocommit=True) goes?

Comment: It is unnecessary in this case. You are explicitly controlling the transaction using the with-statement, compared to using autocommit.

Comment: do I need to close the conn?

Comment: No, the context management handles that as well. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#using-transactions.

Comment: By the way I'm running PyMySQL 0.9.2 so I don't think the issue on github is related...

Comment: Well, no. MySQL DDL cannot be rolled back. Just remembered that and will have to rewrite the answer quite a bit. The issue on github is very much related. The change was introduced in version 0.8, and as such relates to 0.9 still.

Comment: This code while runs.. does not solve my problem... I created a failure on the 2nd query (gave a table name that doesn't exist). The code fails but the 1st query did not abort. This means I have TRUNCATE  the production table but did not insert any data... I need both commands to run together or don't run at all.

Comment: See the above comment. MySQL DDL is not transactional in the sense that you could roll back the effects of DDL statements.

Comment: So what can I do? In Postresql there is a block statement with begin and end that runs as one session. I don't know what is the equivalent here

Comment: `executemany()` is for running the same statement with different parameters many times. It does not help. In MySQL you are out of luck, if you want transactional DDL. The renaming trick may reduce the possibility of inconsistent state.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that I'm the first one who faces this issue.. It's very common to work with stage and production tables