# Django unit test taking a long time to run

Tags: mysql, django

I tried different approaches like `python manage.py test --keepdb`and creating a separate test database.
I'm getting an error -:

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test_b2b` ;\n                    SET sql_notes = @' at line 2")
```

I'm using MySQL as a database.
Django version - 2.1.7
PyMySQL==1.0.2

Comment: It looks like `test_b2b` has a start quote but not and end quote.

Comment: that's not the problem. it happened by mistake while copy-pasting the question. it's working when I give the command "python manage.py test api" (api is the name of the app) without the flag --keepdb. but it takes a long time like 4 minutes.

Comment: This looks like [a really old django version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/32153634262b7527b8933327d0ce7926647e0d93/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py) that has its code removed a while ago. Assuming this is still the syntax being implemented I checked and sql_notes is executed. `cursor.execute` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518677/mysqldb-cursor-execute-cant-run-multiple-queries#36121851) is mean to take a single sql statement only. Putting django and mysql versions in the question would be good.

Comment: Django 2.1. I have edited the question. please have a look.

Comment: I have answered the question. please accept answer or comment if unacceptable. Note for next question, the MySQL version is the version of the MySQL server returned by `SELECT VERSION()`.

Answer (score 0):

[2.1](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) is an unsupported version that has a bug.

It was [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9a88c6dd6aa84a1b35e585faa0058a0996cc7ed7) in 2.2a1.

If you which to continue with this version, edit the code to remove the two `SET .. sql_notes` lines where the error is so that all that remains is:

```
cursor.execute('''
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %(dbname)s %(suffix)s
''' % parameters)
```